# Sub-query in MongoDB for return a single element with a specific field

Tags: mongodb, join, mongoose, objectid

I have two collections, where one has an array with the IDs of the other. I need to return an element from the first collection and an element from the second collection but only the element that has a specific field. I'll clarify down.

I tried to do something using it but couldn't quite understand the operation.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

My Question:

```
{
  "solved": false,
  "answer": [
     "5d969dbf7d496a256443eeca",
     "5d969f7b7d496a256443eecb"
  ],
  "_id": "5d93dfaf40024619dcc61896",
  "user": "5d8963afa0014a289c8d7112",
  "title": "Ola mundo",
  "description": "esse e um teste",
  "discipline": "5d8fb8e04becf712f8293b5b",
  "createdAt": "2019-10-01T23:22:23.168Z",
  "__v": 0
},
```

My Awnsers

```
{
  "official": false,
  "_id": "5d969dbf7d496a256443eeca",
  "description": "Toma aqui a sua resposta",
  "createdAt": "2019-10-04T01:17:51.454Z",
  "__v": 0
},
```

```
{
  "official": true,
  "_id": "5d969f7b7d496a256443eecb",
  "description": "Esste e um teeeeste",
  "createdAt": "2019-10-04T01:25:15.829Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

I need return the Question Model, and the Awnser Model where the "official" field equals "true". I'm new to mongoDB so I'm asking for help. 
I thought there might be something like sub-query in sql.

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc Yes, I'm using in NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you already using mongoose so you can use [populate with query condition](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) to solve your problem. Something like:

```
Question.find(...).populate({
  path: 'answer',
  match: { official: true}
})
```

Comment: This works very fine,
I did some tests and all returned correct.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use aggregation.

You need to join all the ids from answer array into the Answer collection using $lookup, then use $filter to filter it by "official".

join the documents from the Answer collection if the _ids are matched

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Answer",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "answer",
        as: "answer"
    }

}
```

The result will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93dfaf40024619dcc61896"),
    "solved" : false,
    "answer" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d969dbf7d496a256443eeca"),
            "official" : false,
            "description" : "Toma aqui a sua resposta",
            "createdAt" : "2019-10-04T01:17:51.454Z",
            "__v" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d969f7b7d496a256443eecb"),
            "official" : true,
            "description" : "Esste e um teeeeste",
            "createdAt" : "2019-10-04T01:25:15.829Z",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "user" : "5d8963afa0014a289c8d7112",
    "title" : "Ola mundo",
    "description" : "esse e um teste",
    "discipline" : "5d8fb8e04becf712f8293b5b",
    "createdAt" : "2019-10-01T23:22:23.168Z",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Now that you joined the documents you can filter it by "official" field by using the $addFields and $filter. $addFields add a new fields to the document https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/. In this solution I use the same field name "answer", it will overwrite the answer array with the filtered documents.

```
{
    $addFields: {
        answer: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$answer",
                as: "answer",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$answer.official", true ] }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d93dfaf40024619dcc61896"),
    "solved" : false,
    "answer" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d969f7b7d496a256443eecb"),
            "official" : true,
            "description" : "Esste e um teeeeste",
            "createdAt" : "2019-10-04T01:25:15.829Z",
            "__v" : 0
        }
    ],
    "user" : "5d8963afa0014a289c8d7112",
    "title" : "Ola mundo",
    "description" : "esse e um teste",
    "discipline" : "5d8fb8e04becf712f8293b5b",
    "createdAt" : "2019-10-01T23:22:23.168Z",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

This is the complete query:

```
db.Question.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        from: "Answer",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "answer",
        as: "answer"
    }

},
{
    $addFields: {
        answer: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$answer",
                as: "answer",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$answer.official", true ] }
            }
        }

    }
}])
```

Comment: I tried to use it in many ways but to no avail, the answer array always returns empty. The explanation was very good and maybe I am doing something wrong.